# Boxstarter For Software Automation

Tags: .net, vagrant, virtual-machine, devops, boxstarter

We are trying to automate our deployment process, we are mainly using .net/Microsoft stack which happen to be a good fit to use CICD like TeamCity and Octopus, however looking into automating the way projects gets installed on local dev machines becomes a challenge thus we started to look for other options to do the job. We have been looking at Docker, Vagrant and Boxstarter given that docker not yet suitable for .net apps as only support up to asp.net core RC we moved into Boxstarter.

The question is can the nuget packages being generated as artifacts for octopus deploy gets packaged as chocolately packages and then Boxstarter create configuration file for it deploy to VM?

We are looking for specifically software developed by us not into automating infrastructure components like IIS or installing .NET, ...etc the point is how we can use Boxstarter to use our private nuget packages to create and deploy our software, as an example a windows service? it is ok to have a VM running on either HyperV or Virtual Box on local dev machines.

Is Boxstarter designed for such thing? or it is more of Vagrant Box to create vagrant file with each project and then gets it deployed to some VM?

Would love your feedback, giving that we are a Microsoft shop and we use .NET, we started using docker for other Infrastructure pieces like Kafka, ES, ...etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at: http://boxstarter.org/Learn/RemotePackageWithArtifacts

This provides details on how to install an application and any windows components etc. that are required onto a target windows host.

If you produce your packages this way, you probably don't need to use octopus (which has some limitations when working with infrastructure-as-code, i.e. need to have specific machine instances, build steps not part of source control)